# Python3: can't open file 'sherlock.py' [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, linux, path, pip, errno

So I am new to Kali Linux and I have installed the infamous Sherlock, nonetheless when I used the command to search for usernames it didn't work (Python3: can't open file 'sherlock.py' [Errno 2] No such file or directory). Naturally I tried to look up at similiar problems and have found that maybe the problem is located on my python path.

Which is currently located in /usr/bin/python/ and my pip is in /usr/local/bin/pip. Is my python and pip installed correctly in the path? If not, how do I set a correct path?

However if it is right and has no correlation with the issue, then what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change directory to sherlock twice. (it works for me)

Comment: Thanks for answering, that's what I figured out too, specifying where sherlock is located everytime I run the application.

Answer (score 0):

I came to find out it is all dependent on how you install it. [sherlock github repo](https://github.com/sherlock-project/sherlock)

The repo doc has a procedure that works perfect.
As it creates a dir for sherlock library files, upon installation.
All you have to do after installing it is basically change directory to the sherlock directory then  run your serach eg . python3 sherlock maryjoseph